# how to add animation on recycler view when usin notifydataset changed

Tags: kotlin, animation, android-recyclerview

i have a grid layout recycler view and 2 xml files for animation named fall_down_animation and layout_animation_fall_down, i send a list which contains a card modal to my recycler view adapter and it adds them with animation but when i add a new item to my list and use ntfydatasetchanged anmation does not work

```
val rand = ('A'..'Z').random()
                courseList.add(CourseRVModal(pastTime%4, rand.toString()))
                courseRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
//thats how i add another modal
```

Answer (score 0):

You avoid using notifyDataSetChanged when updating items in recycler view adapter. If you want to add an item and notify the adapter then you need to use notifyItemInserted.

Your animation might kick-in when using it.

Comment: it didnt work :/